# strange inability to require config/boot after upgrading to ruby 1.9.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I upgraded my ruby to 1.9.2 and now when I try to start up a Rails 2.3.5 app with script/server I get this error:

```
<internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require': no such file to load -- script/../config/boot (LoadError)
        from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
        from script/server:2:in `<main>'
```

But script/server:2 definitely looks correct, and the file config/boot.rb exists in the right place.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Replacing line 2 of script/server with

```
require File.expand_path('../../config/boot', __FILE__)
```

works for me (taken from Rails 3)

Comment: Tried this but still get script/server
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- test/unit/error (LoadError)
 from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require' What am I missing?

Answer (score 83):

Much simpler, does not require modification of all scripts:

Instead of:

```
script/server
```

call:

```
./script/server
```

Comment: This was awesome. Helped me with Gitorious.

Comment: File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../confg/boot' (used in server) takes dirname from the invoking command. When you call 'script/server', it tries to find 'script/../config/boot' using LOAD_PATH (unsuccessfully). When you call './script/server', it translates to './script/../config/boot' - with current dir explicit in the path.

Comment: tried this too, but it's not working: script/server
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- test/unit/error (LoadError)
 from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'

Answer (score 13):

it's because ruby 1.9.2 doesn't add the current directory in the LOAD_PATH.

Add this that in top of your script/server file:

```
$: << File.dirname(__FILE__)
```

Or in your case:

```
$: << File.dirname(__FILE__) + '..'
```

Comment: not working: ./server
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- . (LoadError)
 from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
 from ./server:3:in `<main>' What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

I met the exact same problem as described.
Ubuntu 10.04 x64, Eclipse Helio, AptanaStudion2 with RadRail, Ruby 1.9.2, Rails 2.3.5
this doesn't work for me:

```
require File.expand_path('../../config/boot', __FILE__)
```

This works for me

```
require File.expand_path(__FILE__)+ '/../../config/boot'
```

Comment: Had a similar problem setting up gitorious, this was my solution as well.

Answer (score 0):

The `$: << File.dirname(__File__) + '..'` won't work since you'd get a dir of

'script..'

Try

```
$: << File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__),'..')
```

Comment: not working: ./server
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- ./.. (LoadError)
 from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
 from ./server:3:in `<main>' What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You might try to add the path 
source /usr/share/ruby-rvm/scripts/rvm

Answer (score 0):

Please check your root path before start padrino.
like if your application in "C:\XXXXXXX\YYYYYYY\ZZZ-padrino" here and you are in "C:\XXXXXXX\YYYYYYY\" in command prompt then this error will occur. 
then you should in "C:\XXXXXXX\YYYYYYY\ZZZ-padrino".