# nginx cannot load such file -- rubygems/path_support

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, nginx

I'm under nginx + passenger + rails 3.2.1 and when i try to start my app i get

```
cannot load such file -- rubygems/path_support
```

the output of gem environment is

```
RubyGems Environment:


- RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.8.23
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.9.3 (2012-11-10 patchlevel 327) [i686-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /root/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /root/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /root/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /root/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
     - /root/.gem/ruby/1.9.1
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/
```

and in my nginx.conf i have

```
user root;

http {
      passenger_root /root/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.19;
      passenger_ruby /root/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/bin/ruby;
    passenger_default_user root;
    passenger_default_group root;
....
```

what else can i check?
Thank you

Comment: does this help? https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/phusion-passenger/ZME8fmoVi2s

Comment: already checked, i have just one user 'root' and all the installing task has been made by himself. root user belongs to root group.

Answer (score 0):

thanks a lot ! the code in your config file saved my life:

```
passenger_default_user root;
passenger_default_group root;
```

I met the same error with your and solved with your config file , the detailed answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15777738/445908