# Can't get rails app to load in production using Ubuntu 14, nginx, and passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, nginx, deployment, rubygems

I have a rails 4 app that runs fine in development on my macbook.
I have followed what seems like a very detailed tutorial on how to deploy the application using:

- Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
- Nginx
- Passenger
- Rails 4.1.5
- Ruby 2.1.2
- RVM

It seems the rails application is failing to load based on [this error here](http://pastebin.com/bMdB3BJd).

... but I am a bit lost.  The message "No such file to load -- Sequence (LoadError)" and subsequent detail don't seem to indicate which thing did not load.

> bundle install

and

> rake db:migrate

... work fine.

> /usr/bin/passenger-config validate-install

... says all is well too.

Review of the Nginx error log yield this exerpt, but I am not sure where it should lead me:

> Could not spawn process for application /var/www/mymri/code: An error
>   occurred while starting up the preloader.

I have enabled friendly errors for Nginx.  This produces a lot of other related information, some of which I probably should not share.

What should I check next to troubleshoot this problem?

EDIT1:

This [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7856034/ruby-on-rails-nginx-passenger-on-production-server-cannot-load-such-file-r?rq=1) does not work for me.  I have confirmed that passenger is running as the same user that owns the files in the application code directory.  I think passenger is finding the rails application correctly, but the application is failing to load some dependancy.

Comment: Possible typo on line 2 of `institutions_controller.rb`. Post the first few lines if you don't already see it.

Comment: Yes.  I had a require 'filename' at that location.  Commented it out and it works fine now.  Can't recall why I put it there.  Don't know why it works in development, but not production.  Thanks for your help.  I sometimes look at the lengthy stack dumps in the rails error messages and wonder where to go next.  I suppose this sort of trial and error is the teacher.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a

> require 'filename'

... at that location. Commented it out and it works fine now. Can't recall why I put it there. Don't know why it works in development, but not production. I sometimes look at the lengthy stack dumps in the rails error messages and wonder where to go next. I suppose this sort of trial and error is the teacher.  The tip-off here was in line #7 of 49 in the error stackdump where it says,

> /var/www/mymri/code/app/controllers/institutions_controller.rb:2:in
>   '< class:InstitutionsController >'

My thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/users/1153362/substantial