# Rails Error - `require': no such file to load -- rubygems (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, rvm

I recently followed some instructions with RVM to install `ruby-debug` and I think it might have caused some problems. The link that I found the instructions are here: http://beginrescueend.com/support/troubleshooting/

The commands I used to install are the following:

```
$ rvm reinstall 1.9.3 --patch debug --force-autoconf
$ gem install ruby-debug19 -- --with-ruby-include="${MY_RUBY_HOME/rubies/src}"
```

Now, when I try to start the rails server, I receive the following error:

```
./bundler_stubs/rails:13:in `require': no such file to load -- rubygems (LoadError)
from ./bundler_stubs/rails:13
```

This SO question would lead me to believe that I have more than one version of rails installed: [no such file to load -- rubygems (LoadError)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2896485/no-such-file-to-load-rubygems-loaderror)

However, when I run `which -a ruby` as the selected answer suggests, I only receive `/usr/bin/ruby`. Any thoughts on what to do here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to explicitly activate the installed Ruby version before using it.

```
rvm use 1.9.3
```

`which ruby` should now point to the new version.

You can set a default Ruby version with

```
rvm --default 1.9.3
```

Another option is to have that Ruby version activated in your project folder. This can be achieved by placing a .rvmrc file there. E.g.

```
echo "rvm use 1.9.3" >> /project/folder/.rvmrc
```

Now you will need to install all your gems (including rubygems, rails etc.) for that particular (rvm) Ruby version, e.g.

```
gem install ruby-debug19
```

Comment: `rvm use 1.9.3 --default` did the trick. For whatever reason, the current version was set to 1.8.7, but I don't know why that is because it used to be default to 1.9.3.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"` to your `.bash_profile` (if you're on a Mac) or your `.bashrc` (if you're in Linux). Seems like your RVM path isn't being loaded, so the wrong Ruby version is being called.