# Problems running rails 2.3.10 bundler `require': no such file to load -- rubygems (LoadError)

Tags: bundler, ruby-on-rails-2, webrick

I have an app on Rails 2.3.10 on production; when I try to start with `ruby script/server -p 3017 -e production -d` it throws me the following error:

```
Rails requires RubyGems >= 1.3.2. Please install RubyGems and try again: http://rubygems.rubyforge.org

try installing passenger to start the project with but it generates another error:

/home/gmcms/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p370@nick_backend/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb:2:in `require': no such file to load -- rubygems (LoadError)
from /home/gmcms/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p370@nick_backend/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb:2
from /home/gmcms/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p370@nick_backend/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/setup.rb:1:in `require'
from /home/gmcms/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p370@nick_backend/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/setup.rb:1
```

I got this project from another developer, and he always started the project this way; before it didn't have a Gemfile, so I created a Gemfile where I defined the gems the project is using and then install everything with bundler adding the parameter `--deployment`:

```
bundle install --deployment
```

I've also followed the steps that are on the official website of bundler:
http://bundler.io/v1.3/rails23.html

But when I try to run the project the same way using ruby script/server it haves me the same error. I followed this threads but none of them worked for me:

- http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/15#page66
- [Rails "no such file to load -- rubygems (LoadError)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14890561/rails-no-such-file-to-load-rubygems-loaderror)
- [no such file to load -- rubygems (LoadError)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2896485/no-such-file-to-load-rubygems-loaderror)

What can I do? Thanks in advance.

Juan Trejo.

Answer (score -1):

I have run into similar issues. Try running

```
     rvm gemset use global && bundle
```