# Reinstalling rubygems

Tags: ruby, rubygems

How do you reinstall RubyGems as mentioned in [no such file to load -- rubygems (LoadError)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2896485/no-such-file-to-load-rubygems-loaderror)?

Running Mac OS X 10.8.2

Comment: What OS are you on? Are you using RVM or rbenv or do you want to install into a default/system Ruby installation?

Answer (score 4):

#### Download it right from the source.

I had massive trouble trying to get `gem update --system` or `gem install rubygems-update` working properly.

The only thing that worked was **downloading right from the source and just overwriting your old version of RubyGems.**

1. Simply download the latest [here](http://rubygems.org/pages/download) *(was 2.0.3 at time of writing)*.
2. Extract the downloaded archive and `cd` into the resulting directory.
3. Run the setup with `ruby setup.rb`. (You may need to use `sudo` for this, but try it without first.)

All good!

JP

Comment: Gosh this was so helpful!

Answer (score -1):

Download the latest version:

```
wget http://...
```

unpack the file:

```
tar xzvf ruby-...
```

and install it:

```
cd ruby-...
./configure
make
make install
```

For control, `ruby --version`

Comment: Might be being a bit pedantic but some actual URLs rather than http://... would help.

Comment: A README suggested using "gem update --system". However, this seems to be an upgrade rather than a reinstall.

Comment: Doesn't this assume a Linux system? The OP didn't state what OS is being used, but from other posts it appears it's Mac OS.