# Unable to use bourbon functions with sass (sass -r bourbon.rb fails)

Tags: ruby, sass, rbenv, bourbon

I am having trouble compiling sass files with functions such as linear-gradient or box-shadow. I am getting exactly the same issue as here https://github.com/thoughtbot/bourbon/issues/68 where the resulting css is just a jumble of `false`'s.

I am not working on a rails project, so I thought I might have to include the bourbon.rb file as a library when doing `sass --watch`, but this is not working for me:

```
sass --watch .:.. --r ./bourbon/lib/bourbon.rb
LoadError: cannot load such file -- bourbon/generator
  Use --trace for backtrace.
```

[no such file to load -- rubygems (LoadError)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2896485/no-such-file-to-load-rubygems-loaderror) here it says that this might indicate I have several versions of Ruby installed, and `which -a ruby` showed both rbenv 1.9.3-p327 as well as just /usr/bin/ruby (I am stil unclear as to what the difference is). Anyway, I moved .rbenv to a backup and supposedly now only have one version of ruby. I also tried specifying the rubygems path

```
echo $RUBYLIB          
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems
```

But I am still getting the same error when trying to include the bourbon.rb file to sass --watch.

Answer (score 1):

Elise, which version of Bourbon are you using? `$bourbon -v`

Since bourbon 3.0, it is no longer required to pass the `--r ./bourbon/lib/bourbon.rb` flag to the sass --watch command.

Please read the new installation instructions here: http://bourbon.io/

Comment: Phil, it seems I was not including the bourbon files correctly, as bourbon -v was saying 'command not found', which is odd, as other bourbon functions were working fine. I reinstalled the gem according to the instructions and am on bourbon version 3.1.0. After removing all border-radius mixins everything seems to work! Still not entirely sure what the issue was, but thanks for your help.