# Trying to load Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I used

```
$ wget -qO- https://toolbelt.heroku.com/install-ubuntu.sh | sh
```

to get heroku toolbelt, but when I tried

```
$ heroku login
```

I got the error

> < internal:gem_prelude>:1:in 'require': cannot load such file -- rubygems.rb (LoadError)
>       from :1:in `< compiled>'

I'm completely new to coding, so I really have no clue what I'm doing. Trying to learn though! FYI, I'm using Ubuntu 12.10 (I tried learning on Windows and I ran into too many problems). I've got ruby 1.9.3p392 and Rails 3.2.12. Thanks so much, let me know if I can add anything to this to make it easier to help. I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

You may have multiple Ruby versions installed and the one you're using is not able to locate the Rubygems library. I would follow similar steps as shown on these pages:

- [no such file to load -- rubygems (LoadError)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2896485/no-such-file-to-load-rubygems-loaderror)
- http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/19#page98

Which Ruby version are you currently seeing this with? Paste the output of `which -a ruby`.

Comment: **$ which -a ruby**

gives

**/home/joaquin/.rvm/bin/ruby**

Only the one install, unfortunately. I had seen that thread earlier and totally reinstalled (at that time, I did in fact have two versions.) Any other ideas?