# To what value PATH variable must be set for using Rspec with Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rubygems

I am having problem with setting PATH variable in Ruby on Rails. Constraints are: I have to use Ruby 1.8.7 and Rails 2.2.2 and Rubygems 1.3.5. These are the outputs of commands:

```
hemant@hemant-laptop:~$ which gem
/usr/bin/gem

hemant@hemant-laptop:~$ which ruby
/usr/local/bin/ruby

hemant@hemant-laptop:~$ which rails
/var/lib/gems/1.8/bin/rails

hemant@hemant-laptop:~$ gem env
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.3.5
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.8.7 (2010-01-10 patchlevel 249) [i486-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /var/lib/gems/1.8
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/ruby1.8
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /var/lib/gems/1.8/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
    - /var/lib/gems/1.8
    - /home/hemant/.gem/ruby/1.8
```

I have added these lines into my `.bashrc` file:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/var/lib/gems/1.8/bin
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin/gem
```

When I echo PATH variable:

```
hemant@hemant-laptop:~$ echo $PATH
```

`usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:bin:/usr/games:/var/lib/gems/1.8/bin:/usr/bin/gem`

Real problem is that when I run `script/server` in my rails app directory, It errors:

`./script/../config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/rails/vendor_gem_source_index.rb:1:in 'require': no such file to load -- rubygems (LoadError)`

When I googled it, I got to know that it is due to flaw in `PATH` variable configuration, but I can't understand what value I should give to it. The above two `export` statements are just hit and trials but they didn't solve the problem.

Can someone please guide me what value `PATH` must be set to and how one can deduce the value from outputs of various commands.

**[EDIT]**

Running `gem list` gives this:

```
actionmailer (2.2.2)
actionpack (2.2.2)
activerecord (2.2.2)
activeresource (2.2.2)
activesupport (2.2.2)
chronic (0.10.2)
diff-lcs (1.2.4)
image_science (1.2.1)
libv8 (3.16.14.3)
mysql (2.9.1)
rack (1.5.2)
rails (2.2.2)
rake (0.8.7)
ref (1.0.5)
rspec (1.2.9)
rspec-core (2.14.6)
rspec-expectations (2.14.0)
rspec-mocks (2.14.4)
rspec-rails (1.2.9)
rubygems-update (2.1.10)
therubyracer (0.12.0)
ZenTest (4.3.0)
```

Comment: can you include a `gem list` so we can inspect the installed versions of gems.

Comment: Does this post helps you out? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2896485/no-such-file-to-load-rubygems-loaderror

Comment: yeah .... that  was wonderful, worked like a charm.... thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

To extend your path with new paths which contain executables you need to specify the directory. For the gem command you now pointing to the executable itself.

Try this:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/var/lib/gems/1.8/bin
```

This should include all executables in your path. Make sure to reload your .bashrc before trying again.

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

One other solution to solve your problems:
Spin-up a virtual machine which is old enough to have the old stuff. Probably ubuntu 12.04 is old enough.

Comment: I tried the export you mentioned but still same error :( and I am using Ubuntu 10.04.4