# spreadsheet load error on production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have got a error when I try to use my ruby on rails application. The error i got:

```
in `require': No such file to load -- spreadsheet (LoadError)
```

My gem list:

```
bundler (1.3.5)
bundler-unload (1.0.2)
executable-hooks (1.2.6)
mini_portile (0.5.2)
rake (10.1.0)
ruby-ole (1.2.11.7)
rubygems-bundler (1.4.2)
rubygems-update (2.1.11)
rubyzip (1.1.0)
rubyzip2 (2.0.2)
rvm (1.11.3.8)
spreadsheet (0.9.6)
```

On my local environment it works. In production it doesn't work.

Could someone help me with that?

Comment: Check the path make sure it is not referencing localhost.

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2896485/no-such-file-to-load-rubygems-loaderror