# Why do I get "No such file to load"?

Tags: ruby, openproject

I am working on installing Open Project and I ran `bundle exec rails server` and got:

```
root@bistro2:/home/openproject/openproject# bundle exec
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/rubygems_ext.rb:8:in `require': no such file to load -- rubygems (LoadError)
        from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/rubygems_ext.rb:8
        from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler.rb:11:in `require'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler.rb:11
        from /usr/bin/bundle:4:in `require'
        from /usr/bin/bundle:4
root@bistro2:/home/openproject/openproject#
```

Comment: What is open project ?

Comment: We need more information. What version of Ruby are you running? How was it installed? Rubygems has been installed with Ruby for several years by default. Also, are you running as "root"? If so, don't do that. Learn about rbenv or RVM, and use that to install Ruby in a sandbox, *then* install into that sandbox.

Comment: Actually you can get the answers for the same problem [no such file to load — rubygems (LoadError)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2896485/no-such-file-to-load-rubygems-loaderror), hope this can help you.

Comment: have you use the `ruby1.8`? if yes you need to install rubygems...

Comment: Open Project is similar to Microsoft Project but Open Source.

Comment: Ruby - V = 2.0 / Gem - V 2.1 / Bundle - V 1.35 / rvm 1.25.5 -- Something were installed via sudo and some where not

Comment: I screwed up somewhere. I followed the documentation exactly from https://www.openproject.org/projects/openproject/wiki/Installation_OpenProject_3_0 to the T

Comment: If you use rvm, bundler shouldn't be used vom /usr/lib/ruby, shouldn't it? You might want to check if you use the rvm-provided bundler and not your system installation. Also, have your trief the new OpenProject version? It has a far more recent software stack - here is the installation guide: https://www.openproject.org/projects/openproject/wiki/Installation_OpenProject_3_0