# `require': no such file to load -- rubygems (LoadError)

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I am trying to create aws pipeline on vm for which i am using ruby1..3 and rubygems 2.0.3.While trying to create pipeline I am getting following error.

```
./aws/core/client.rb:14:in `require': no such file to load -- rubygems (LoadError)
```

Please help me with this problem....

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are having problems with your ruby/gem installation. 
Maybe you have 2 ruby version installed simultaneously on the same machine?

Although not exactly the same question, but it seems that you can try the solutions described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2896485/no-such-file-to-load-rubygems-loaderror) stackoverflow thread.